# Error creating bean: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was migrating my project from spring-hibernate version3.x to 4.x, but faced the following error.

**Console Log**

```
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:51 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
WARNING: Name = param Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "20" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:51 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private drdo.param.Dao.AdminDao drdo.param.ServiceImpl.AdminServiceImpl.aDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AdminDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory drdo.param.utility.DaoSessionManager.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: drdo.param.Entity.ProjectReview.ABCFromTime
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private drdo.param.Dao.AdminDao drdo.param.ServiceImpl.AdminServiceImpl.aDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AdminDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory drdo.param.utility.DaoSessionManager.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: drdo.param.Entity.ProjectReview.ABCFromTime
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AdminDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory drdo.param.utility.DaoSessionManager.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: drdo.param.Entity.ProjectReview.ABCFromTime
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory drdo.param.utility.DaoSessionManager.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: drdo.param.Entity.ProjectReview.ABCFromTime
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: drdo.param.Entity.ProjectReview.ABCFromTime
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: drdo.param.Entity.ProjectReview.ABCFromTime
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.setType(SimpleValueBinder.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2238)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3790)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3744)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 47 more

Nov 09, 2021 9:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ABC_PA_New_13jun] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [ABC_PA_New_13jun] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [ABC_PA_New_13jun] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8083"]
Nov 09, 2021 9:18:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7922 ms
```

**ProjectReview.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.validation.constraints.Future;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Entity
@Validated
@Table(name = "PROJECT_REVIEW")
public class ProjectReview implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "SEQ_PROJECT_REVIEW", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="MEETING_REF", updatable=false)
    private MeetingNameMaster meetingName;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CLUSTER_REF", updatable=false)
    private Esst cluster;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    @Future
    @Column(name="REVIEW_DATE")
    private Date reviewDate;
    @NotBlank
    private String venue;
    @Column(name="CHAIR_NAME")
    private String chairName;
    @Column(name="CHAIR_DESG")
    private String chairDesg;
    @Column(name="COCHAIR_NAME")
    private String coChairName;
    @Column(name="COCHAIR_DESG")
    private String coChairDesg;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name="ABC_FROM_TIME")
    private String ABCFromTime;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name="ABC_TO_TIME")
    private String ABCToTime;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name="CONCLUSION_FROM_TIME")
    private String conclusionFromTime;
   @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name="CONCLUSION_TO_TIME")
    private String conclusionToTime;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createDate;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CREATED_BY_USER", updatable=false)
    private User createdBy;
    private int freeze=0;
    private String status="active";
    
    public ProjectReview() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MeetingNameMaster getMeetingName() {
        return meetingName;
    }

    public void setMeetingName(MeetingNameMaster meetingName) {
        this.meetingName = meetingName;
    }

    public Esst getCluster() {
        return cluster;
    }

    public void setCluster(Esst cluster) {
        this.cluster = cluster;
    }

    public Date getReviewDate() {
        return reviewDate;
    }

    public void setReviewDate(Date reviewDate) {
        this.reviewDate = reviewDate;
    }

    public String getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(String venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }

    public String getChairName() {
        return chairName;
    }

    public void setChairName(String chairName) {
        this.chairName = chairName;
    }

    public String getChairDesg() {
        return chairDesg;
    }

    public void setChairDesg(String chairDesg) {
        this.chairDesg = chairDesg;
    }

    public String getCoChairName() {
        return coChairName;
    }

    public void setCoChairName(String coChairName) {
        this.coChairName = coChairName;
    }

    public String getCoChairDesg() {
        return coChairDesg;
    }

    public void setCoChairDesg(String coChairDesg) {
        this.coChairDesg = coChairDesg;
    }

    public String getABCFromTime() {
        return ABCFromTime;
    }

    public void setABCFromTime(String ABCFromTime) {
        this.ABCFromTime = ABCFromTime;
    }

    public String getABCToTime() {
        return ABCToTime;
    }

    public void setABCToTime(String ABCToTime) {
        this.ABCToTime = ABCToTime;
    }

    public String getConclusionFromTime() {
        return conclusionFromTime;
    }

    public void setConclusionFromTime(String conclusionFromTime) {
        this.conclusionFromTime = conclusionFromTime;
    }

    public String getConclusionToTime() {
        return conclusionToTime;
    }

    public void setConclusionToTime(String conclusionToTime) {
        this.conclusionToTime = conclusionToTime;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public User getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(User createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public int getFreeze() {
        return freeze;
    }

    public void setFreeze(int freeze) {
        this.freeze = freeze;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

   
}
```

Comment: You need to fix this error : Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: drdo.param.Entity.ProjectReview.ABCFromTime

Comment: `ProjectReview` post this class code, you are using `@Temporal` at the wrong place.

Comment: I have posted ProjectReview.java   Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

@Temporal error is related to date operations, maybe you're trying to make operation between dates but some of date is null or undefined.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using SpringBoot, which may solve your problem

Comment: The question is nothing do with sprint boot usage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).